# Swift string iterate and compare

Tags: swift, string

I'm playing on the website CodinGame. The task is to find the number closest to zero. This is what you are given.

```
let n = Int(readLine()!)! // the number of temperatures to analyse
let temps = readLine()! // the n temperatures expressed as integers ranging from -273 to 5526
```

I have no idea what to do. I'm guessing there is many way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a `String` containing something like `"4 -6 8 12 -12"` and you want extract the `Int` closest to zero.

Here's the solution

```
import Foundation

let text = "4 -6 8 12 -12"
let numbers = text.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").flatMap { Int($0) }
if let closestToZero = numbers.minElement({ abs($0) < abs($1)}) {
    print(closestToZero) // -1
}
```

### Compact version

Same logic, less code

```
let closestToZero = text.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    .flatMap { Int($0) }
    .minElement{ abs($0) < abs($1) }
```

Comment: sorry for the vague question. temps is a String. "4 -6 8 12 -12"

Comment: @BobbyB: no problem, I updated my code please take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think thats what i need but it dosen't seem to work. got this error    Answer.swift:19:15: error: value of type 'String' has no member 'componentsSeparatedByString'      I think the website dose not handle    swift    like it should.

Comment: @BobbyB: Because you need to `import Foundation`

Comment: yeah that was it. thank you. I think I was having problems because of the not `import Foundation` now i need to figure out the closure. the journey is going to be long.